# Insufficient privileges to complete the operation when using service principal to create Azure AD Application

Tags: azure, azure-ad-graph-api

Following the code outlined here:

```
https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-graphapi-console/blob/master/GraphConsoleAppV3/Program.cs#L810
```

but using a Service Principal to authenticate one will get a Insufficient Privileges error when trying to create the application on

```
client.Applications.AddApplicationAsync(appObject).Wait();
```

with token exchange like the following:

```
var context = new AuthenticationContext($"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantId}");
var token = context.AcquireToken("https://graph.windows.net", new ClientCredential(clientId, secret));    
var client = new ActiveDirectoryClient(new Uri($"https://graph.windows.net/{tenantId}"),()=>Task.FromResult(token.AccessToken));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

its required that the application has been given the Administrator role that currently seem only possible to add using the powershell tools for azure AD: https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/jj151815.aspx#bkmk_installmodule

and using `connect-msolservice` and using your Azure Ad Administrator user login when prompted.

1. `connect-msolservice`
2. `Get-MsolServicePrincipal –AppPrincipalId {appId}`
3. `Add-MsolRoleMember -RoleMemberType ServicePrincipal -RoleName 'Company Administrator' -RoleMemberObjectId {objectID}`

where the objectID is the output of the 2 command

Comment: Thanks for this info. However, when I try to do this I get the following error message: **Access Denied. You do not have permissions to call this cmdlet**. Any idea how to address that?