# Azure AD Graph API call gives "Insufficient privileges to complete the operation" exception

Tags: azure

We are trying to call the Azure AD graph API to get user information. For that we have followed the steps mentioned at https://github.com/OfficeDev/O365-ASPNETMVC-Start. But when we make a call to the https://graph.windows.net/microsoft.onMicrosoft.com/users/?api-version=1.0 URL and see fiddler response, we get an exception as below:
 HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
 Content-Type: application/json;odata=minimalmetadata

```
{
    "odata.error":
    {
        "code":"Authorization_RequestDenied","message":
        {
            "lang":"en","value":"Insufficient privileges to complete the operation."
        }
    }
}
```

We tried following the steps mentioned at [Insufficient privileges to complete the operation when using service principal to create Azure AD Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34911351/insufficient-privileges-to-complete-the-operation-when-using-service-principal-t) but got message indicating that appid doesnt have admin permissions to perform the changes. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

As shown in this image, change permissions in Your registered Bot Application to get permissions.

[image: Image Link]

and also Check your "Scope" parameter in URL.