# In Azure cloud, how to manage group user without Global admin and limited admin?

Tags: azure-active-directory

In Azure cloud, how to manage group user without Global admin and limited admin? This functionality we want to provide by application(c# or RestAPI).

Comment: I have taken reference of the code downloaded from https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-graphapi-web

Comment: Did you have any update for this issue?

Comment: Issue is resolved by following steps which shown in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34911351/insufficient-privileges-to-complete-the-operation-when-using-service-principal-t

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you were requesting the Azure Graph REST with the delegated permission scopes.

Delegated permission scopes are for apps that a user signs in to. These scopes delegate the privileges of the signed-in user to the app, allowing the app to act as the signed in user. **The actual privileges granted to the app will be the least privileged combination (the intersection) of the privileges granted by the scope and those possessed by the signed-in user**. For example, if the permission scope grants delegated privileges to write all directory objects, but the signed-in user has privileges only to update their own user profile, the app will only be able to write the signed-in user's profile but no other objects.

Based on my understanding, to manage group membership, the user could be the **owner of the group** or the admin of that tenant. If you want to manage the group membership without admin, you can assign the users who you want to manage the group membership to the owner of that group.

And since the scopes `Group.ReadWrite.All`, `Directory.AccessAsUser.All` is required for calling the Azure AD Graph REST for the owner of group, your web app need to perform the [admin consent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-devhowto-multi-tenant-overview#understanding-user-and-admin-consent) to grant these scopes to the web app for the normal users.

Comment: We have implemented but still don't able to manage group(remove member, add member) with normal user.

Comment: Please check the whether scopes were shown in the token from this [site](https://jwt.io/). If not, we need to grant the permission again to make the new permissions work. Please append the parameter `prompt=consent` when you initiate the request for the authorization code( refer [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-protocols-oauth-code) about this parameter).